# AngularJS: Access directive's attribute from another attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined a custom checkbox directive, and I will like to access an attribute from within another attribute.

Please note the `disabled` and `ng-class` attributes in the following example:

```
<checkbox ng-model="isChecked" 
          disabled="<some angular expression>" 
          ng-class="{'fresh': isChecked && !disabled}"/>
```

Also, the scope of the directive looks like this:

```
scope: {
    ngModel: "=",
    disabled: "=",
}
```

Is this possible ?

**EDIT:**

To make my question more clear: In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFN7Q/3/) I illustrate how I want to reuse the attribute `disabled` in my `ng-class` attribute.

In the fiddle, this will never work because `disabled` in the `ng-class` attribute is always false (it's not the attribute disabled of the checkbox (or the disabled from the scope of the directive) but rather the 'disabled' from the current scope).

Comment: in template u can access the artribute like {{arrributename}} . In link function you can access it with scope.attributename. for attribute access use "@" not "="

Comment: If that is so, shouldn't the above example work just nice ?

Comment: There is no problem with accessing attribute value through scope. Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/eFN7Q/1/

Comment: @Pythonic I updated my question to be more clear about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As @surendar mentioned in [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) expression evaluation can be possible through `ngAttr attribute bindings` means

```
scope: {
    ngModel: "=",
    disabled: "@"
}
```

`ng-class` will be evaluated with model value `isChecked`

**Edit**

It seems what you are trying to do is not possible !

```
disabled="<some angular expression>"
```

Because `disabled` is `attribute` for directive and same time it is `model` for **directive's inside element**.

```
ng-class="{'fresh': isChecked && !disabled}"
```

here `ng-class` expect `isChecked` and `disabled` are model property. You can do something else like

```
ng-class="{'fresh': isChecked && (expression)}" // you can put expression instead of disabled
```

otherwise you need link/controller.

Comment: I don't see how this can solve my issue ... I know what attribute binding is, but I want to do the logic for ngClass in the template, not in the link/controller function.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. For now I do what you said, putting the expression 2 times in the code, but I thought there is a more pretty way, and reusing the disable attribute seemed like one solution.